# Animate Transition of CollectionView in TableViewCell

Tags: ios

I'm trying to figure out a way to animate the layout of a UICollectionView which is embedded in a UITableviewCell.

The reason why I did it is simple, I needed to have different UICollectionView in different section of my UITableview to be able to scroll horizontally through each UICollectionViews. It was easy, but now I'd like to animate the transition when I touch a cell in the UICollectionView and the entire collection grow and became a page view (full screen) where I can display more information in each cell of my UICollectionView.

As I don't use as parent a UICollectionViewController, I can't properly use the UICollectionViewLayoutTransition.

My first try was to expand the height of the cell where my UICollectionView was embedded in with:

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    self.expandedIndexPath = tableViewIndexPath;

    [collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:_largeLayout animated:YES completion:nil];
    [collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Bad guess because the heigh of the cell did indeed grow but I forgot that the other section of the UITableView was still in the view so I was able to continue to scroll in the tableview which I do not want.

So my second thought is to do a navigation controller transitioning but how can I animate the entire UICollectionView of just one section of my UITableView to grow as the PhotoApp do ?

Thanks everyone for you help.

Comment: [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [collectionView reloadData];
} completion:nil];